# Macbook Internal Speakers works only when headphones are plugged In

Tags: macbook-pro, mac

I have a strange scenario with my Mac Pro, my internal speakers don't work normally, it works only when my headphone is plugged In.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Kindly [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/333491/edit) the question to clarify if you are facing the problem with your MacBook or Mac Pro.

Comment: In addition to what @NimeshNeema said, please add your OS version and what steps you've already taken to resolve the problem.  See [ask] for more info.

Comment: if you internal speakers only work when you plug in headphones (assuming your headphones work properly), there's an issue with your headphone jack.  There's an internal "switch" that tells the system which audio device is connected - that's probably being shorted.  See:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/238630/headset-plugged-in-via-y-adapter-and-extension-cable-stopped-working/238639#238639

Answer (score 1):

Here's what happened when I encountered the same issue. The "Use audio port for:" was selected to "Sound Input" - in the system preferences. I had to plug in my headphones and then change it to "Sound Output" (it wouldn't let me make that change unless I had something plugged into the audio port). I started playing some music on my computer and confirmed that it was now sending the audio through the headphones. While the music was still playing I unplugged the headphones and the audio switched to my internal speakers. From then on it worked correctly when the headphones were not plugged in and would switch to the headphones when they were plugged in.

Side note: I often change the Input/Output of my audio port for recording purposes. Sometimes if the microphone that is plugged into the audio port gets unplugged while a recording is still in progress, it throws the computer off and it can't figure out what to do when something is plugged into the audio port or not. This is my solution every time and it always works for me. Hope it helps.