# 3.5mm jack on 2021 MacBook Pro stopped taking line-in input

Tags: audio, headphones, microphone, garageband

I have a 14" MacBook Pro with M1, 2021.

Last week I had my electric piano plugged into the Mac via the 3.5mm cable and the Mac was receiving the audio stream from that input just fine. (I used the stream to record in GarageBand.)

Now, with the exact same setup, I cannot get any sound to appear in the microphone from my keyboard. The input is set to "External Microphone" with type "Microphone port". I've tried restarting the laptop and the keyboard, I've tried different cables, etc, with no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The 3.5mm jack is likely broken.  Similar Q/A: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/238639/119271. Different computer and slightly different application  but answer is exactly the same.

Comment: Just remembered that 2015 and newer MBP models no longer had line in; just microphone.  You were sending libe level input to a mic input. See this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/385028/119271

Comment: Thanks @Allan -- I saw that post, but what is odd to me is that sometimes I definitely *can* record with an external microphone. The audio seems well-boosted enough, I have multiple records of it. I would understand if it *never* worked but what is odd is that it is flaky and *sometimes* works.