# 3.5mm Headphone output stopped working in 2019 iMac

Tags: audio, imac, headphones

**The post that I was referred to as an "answer" does not answer this, so I am reposting.

So idk when this started, but I just noticed that my audio was coming from the computer and not the speakers. I've tested and cleaned everything. The speakers work, everything works as it should if I plug it into my MacBook so it's not that. I plugged headphones in, and still nothing. Even when they're plugged in, the audio continues to come through the imac speakers. Wiggling it around does nothing. Not even a hint of audio.

Headphones don't show up as an output option in audio settings. Not sure they ever did.

All audio settings are good. I did the coreaudiod quit process and everything else I've seen. It makes no sense and it's a major problem for me atm.

in Activity Monitor, when searching headphones" This shows up but i dont know what it is. HeadphoneSettingsExtension (system Settings) (620) Screenshot attached.[image]

Comment: Also see: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/238630/119271. It’s not a software issue. When you plug in, there’s a physical switch that disables the speakers. What you describe is a failure of the audio jack

Comment: Please don't repost a question which is on hold, address the "on hold" reason to have it reviewed for reopening. Based on what do you assume that the post referred to as an answer doesn't actually answer your question?

Comment: man nothing was ON HOLD. I deleted the original post and ya'll keep marking it closed when I'm trying to have a goddamn discussion about it. Not just get sent links to other posts that are similar, but after reading them do NOT address my issue. This forum seems to be absolute trash now. great job.

Comment: Based on the symptoms you describe, the answers to the existing questions also apply in your case. If you have additional information about the problems you are facing which contradict the „it‘s the small switch in the headphone port“, please edit them into the question.

Comment: @nohillside "its the small switch in the headphone port".... what? man this has nothing to do with my issue. at all. forget it. This forum is absolutely useless.

Comment: I read your description as „macOS doesn‘t detect headphones/external speakers if I plug them in via the audio jack“. If this isn‘t the problem you are facing, please elaborate.